# How to properly return tuple with objects

Tags: typescript, tuples

Below, I have a function that returns a tuple with 2 objects.

```
const example = () => {
    return [{meow: true}, { woof: false}]
}

const [catStuff, dogStuff] = example()

catStuff.meow // why is this possibly undefined? why does this possibly contain `woof`?
```

I am curious why there is a union? How can I get this tuple to return two distinct objects?

```js
catStuff: {
    meow: boolean,
    woof?: undefined
} | {
    woof: boolean,
    meow?: undefined
}
```

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as an image...

Comment: @HereticMonkey the image is not code it is typescript type assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T {
  return args;
}

const example = () => {
  return tuple({meow: true}, { woof: false})
}
```

The compiler correctly infers:

```
const example: () => [{
    meow: boolean;
}, {
    woof: boolean;
}]
```

I took `tuple` function from [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions #24897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)

For readonly tuples, you can use:

```
const example = () => {
  return [{meow: true}, { woof: false}] as const;
}
```

Here, compiler infers

```
const example: () => readonly [{
    readonly meow: true;
}, {
    readonly woof: false;
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked **why**. It depends on what you are trying to do with the result. As far as Typescript is concerned, your tuple can be interpreted as

> [typescript] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{
>   meow: boolean; woof?: undefined; } | { woof: boolean; meow?:
>   undefined; }'.

And so for example the following and similar usage should work fine:

```
const example = () => {
    return [{meow: true}, { woof: false}]
}

const [catStuff, dogStuff] = example()

console.log(`${catStuff.meow}`)
console.log(`${dogStuff.woof}`)
```

The following will not work

```
console.log(`${dogStuff.meow}`)
console.log(`${catStuff.woof}`)
```

The reason `catStuff.woof` compiles is because Typescript only checks whether `woof` exists in the tuple; it doesn't check which element it's associated with. But at run time however, since `woof` is not defined for `catStuff` you will get an `undefined`.

The following will not compile because `speak` doesn't exist in the tuple/object type:

```
console.log(`${catStuff.speak}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `example` being a function; if you define the return value as a constant directly, you get the same inference:

```js
const c = [{ meow: true }, { woof: false }];
// c: ({ meow: boolean, woof?: undefined } | { woof: boolean, meow?: undefined })[]
```

The underlying reason is that Typescript infers a literal array to have an array type, even though it could infer a tuple type which would be more specific. This was [raised as an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13883) on the Typescript issue tracker in 2017, but the issue was closed without action. This is possibly because, [as one commenter noted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13883#issuecomment-298312159),

> It is really unsafe to infer tuple types... There is a lot of discussion on this in other issues. It would and could break a lot of other code where someone is using an array that they don't intend to be a tuple. ... Just because an array literal is a const and is heterogeneous doesn't mean that it is intended to be a tuple. Especially because even with tuple types, all the run-time array functionality is available.

That is, even though `c` is declared as a `const` reference to an array, the contents of `c` can still be changed by other code, e.g. `c.pop()`, so it would be unsafe in general to assume that `c` will always have exactly two elements of these two distinct types in this order.

---

If you want the function `example` to have a different return type, just add an explicit type annotation:

```js
type MeowWoof = [{ meow: boolean }, { woof: boolean }];

const example: () => MeowWoof = () => {
    return [{ meow: true }, { woof: false }]
};
```

Note also that the most specific possible type for `c` would be `[{ meow: true }, { woof: false }]`, not `[{ meow: boolean }, { woof: boolean }]`.